# How to say two things are the most important of something

Tags: meaning

I am not a native guy and I am having problem with the following sentence. I would like to know is the following sentence right?

The `A` and `B` are of the most important challenges facing the today world.

Comment: I would likely drop the *of* and change *most important* to ***primary***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options:

> - A and B are the two most important challenges ...
> - A and B are the (key / primary) challenges ...

These statements are all absolute, and mean that there are no other more important "challenges ...". To soften this a bit:

> - A and B are (two of / some of / among) the (most important / key / primary) challenges ...